# How is external memory, internal memory, and cache organized?

Tags: memory, caching, cpu

Consider a system as follows: a hardware board having say ARM Cortex-A8 and Neon Vector coprocessor, and Embedded Linux OS running on Cortex-A8. On this environment, if some application - say, a video decoder - is executing, then:

- How is it decided which buffers would be in external memory, which ones would be allocated in internal SRAM, etc.
- When one calls calloc/malloc on such a system/code, the pointer returned is from which memory: internal or external?
- Can a user make buffers to be allocated in the memories of his choice (internal/external)?
- In ARM architectures, there is another memory called "tightly coupled memory" (TCM). What is that and how can user enable and use it?  Can I declare buffers in this memory?
- Do I need to see the memory map (if any) of the hardware board to understand about all these different physical memories present in a typical hardware board?
- How much of a role does the OS play in distinguishing these different memories?

Sorry for multiple questions, but i think they all are interlinked.

Comment: What do you mean by internal versus external memory?  You already mention cache separately, so I assume neither "internal memory" nor "external memory" is part of cache.  Are you using "internal memory" to refer to some on-chip RAM provided by the Cortex-A8?

Comment: @Dale: By internal memory i mean - Fast access on chip memory. External memory = high latency memory off-chip memory, Cache is separate, lets say L1 cache.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please note that I'm not familiar with the ARM nor embedded Linux's specifically, so all of my comments will be from a general point of view.

First, about cache:  Very early during boot, the operating system will do some amount of cache initialization.  Exactly what this entails will vary from processor to processor, but the net effect is to ensure cache is initialized properly, and then enable its use by the processor. After this, the cache is operated exclusively by the processor with no further interaction by the operating system or your programs.

Now, on to external (off-chip) and internal (on-chip) memories:

The operating system owns all hardware on the system, including the internal and external memories and so is ultimately responsible for discovering, configuring, and allocating these resources within the kernel and to user processes. In a typical system (eg, your desktop or a 1u server) there won't usually be any special internal (on-chip) ram, and so the operating system can treat all dram equally.  It will go into a general pool of pages (usually 4k) for allocation to processes, file system buffers, etc.  On a system with special memory of various sorts (nvram, high-speed on-chip memory, and a few others), the operating system's general policies aren't usually correct.

How this is presented to the user will depend on choices made while porting the OS to this system.

- One could modify the OS to be explicitly aware of this special memory, and provide special system calls to allocate it to to user land processes.  However, this could be quite a bit of work unless the embedded linux being used has  at least some support for this sort of thing.
- The approach I'd probably take would be to avoid modifying the kernel itself, and instead write a device driver for the internal memory.  A driver of this sort would typically provide some sort of `mmap` interface to allow user processes to get simple address-based access to the internal memory.

Here are answers to some of your concrete questions.

> How much of a role does the OS play in distinguishing these different memories?

If your system has taken the device driver approach described above, then the OS probably knows only about external memory, or perhaps just enough about the internal memories to initialize them properly although that would likely be in the device driver too, if at all possible.  If the OS knows more explicitly about the on-chip memory, then it will definitely contain any needed initialization code, as well as some sort of scheme to provide access to the user processes.

> How is it decided which buffers would be in external memory, which ones would be allocated in internal SRAM, etc.

It seems unlikely to me that the operating system would try to automate such choices.  Instead, I  suspect that either the OS or a device driver would provide a generic interface to provide access to the on-chip memory, and leave it up to your user code to decide what to do with it.

> When one calls calloc/malloc on such a system/code, the pointer returned is from which memory: internal or external?

Almost certainly, `malloc` and friends will return pointers into the general off-chip memory.  In the driver-based approach suggested above, you'd use `mmap` to gain access to the on-chip memory.  If you needed to do finer-grained allocation than that, you'd need to write your own allocator, or find one that can be given an explicit region of memory to work in.

> Can a user make buffers to be allocated in the memories of his choice (internal/external)?

If by *buffers* you mean the regions returned from the standard `malloc` calls, probably not.  But, if you mean "can a user program somehow get a pointer to the on-chip memory", then the answer is almost certainly yes, but the mechanism will depend on choices made when porting linux to this system.

> In ARM architectures, there is another memory called "tightly coupled memory" (TCM). What is that and how can user enable and use it? Can I declare buffers in this memory?

I don't know what this is.  If I had to guess, I'd assume it's just another form of on-chip ram, but since it has a different name, perhaps I'm wrong.

> Do I need to see the memory map (if any) of the hardware board to understand about all these different physical memories present in a typical hardware board?

If the OS and/or device drivers have provided some sort of abstract access to these memory regions, then you won't need to know explicitly about the address map.  This knowledge is, however, needed to implement this access in either the kernel or a device driver.

I hope this helps somewhat.

Comment: Regarding TCM, it's fast memory. Very much like cache--in fact, in most devices, memory can be configured as TCM or cache--except that content is static: if you store data in there, it is guaranteed to stay.  You would use it to store code and data to which you need fast access and for which you cannot afford the unpredictability of using cache.  E.g. critical interrupt routines or any very time-critical code where you think you can be (and it is worth being) smarter than cache allocation mechanisms.